# Import a large .sas7bdat file

Tags: r, sas

I want to import a file named mret7018.sas7bdat in RStudio but I have two issues.

- First I get a message that the file is too large to open in the source editor (1GB instead of the max 5MB).
- Secondly I do not know what exactly the file type is.

Comment: Where did the file come from?  Can't you ask the provider for format information?

Comment: From the help page of haven::write_sas(): "write_sas() creates sas7bdat files. Unfortunately the SAS file format is complex and undocumented, so write_sas() is unreliable and in most cases SAS will not read files that it produces."

Sounds like it's better to avoid the sas7bdat format (outside of SAS at least). Is there a chance to request an xpt file instead?

From the help page of haven::read_xpt(): "The SAS transport format is a open format, as is required for submission of the data to the FDA."

xpt should be less problematic to import to R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a file from SAS to me.

Maybe try `haven::read_sas()`. Once its read into a `data.frame` it should be possible to proceed with regular R knowledge.